# Self-referencing in EF core Error: the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key same table constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a `Category` model with self-reference and worked fine on creating database yet when I try to insert a parent category (an entity without parentId) I get the error pointing to the foreign-key "ParentId", but it works fine when I insert a topel manually with insert script in SSMS and works fine with ef core when adding a subcategory (an entity which has a parentId)

Category Model

```
public class Category : ICategory
{
    public Category()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateTimeStamp { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdateTimeStamp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Title).IsUnique();
            entity.HasOne(e => e.User).WithMany(e => e.CreatedCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatorUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Parent).WithMany(e => e.Children).HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId).IsRequired(false);
        });
```

Migration

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Categories",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
                Photo = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                IsEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                CreateTimeStamp = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                LastUpdateTimeStamp = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                CreatorUserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ParentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            }
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Categories", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Categories_Users_CreatorUserId",
                    column: x => x.CreatorUserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Categories_Categories_ParentId",
                    column: x => x.ParentId,
                    principalTable: "Categories",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
}
```

I marked "ParentId" nullable anyway I could yet ef core is preventing me though the SQL Server is fine with it!

Error message inner exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Categories_Categories_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "Unknown_Db", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: @vernou of course. question updated

Comment: Which version of C# and EFC are you using?

Comment: @Carlos EFC 3.1.6

Comment: Can you include the EF Core command log? Adding new category with `Parent = null` and `ParentId = null` should work, so something must be missing in the example model/configuration, or the database is not the same as indicated by the migration.

Comment: can you show the foreignKey that was being created in the migration as well? What ReferentialAction does the FK use? It should look something like this:
`table.ForeignKey(name: "FK_Categories_Categories_ParentId", column: x => x.ParentId,
principalTable: "Categories",
principalColumn: "Id",
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);`

Comment: @Carlos Sure Added

Comment: If you add  `optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();` to the optionsbuilder in the OnConfiguring method in your DbContext and try it again, there will be more information in your Output window. Could you try that and update your question?

Comment: as @IvanStoev already said, the migration looks okay and your code should work. Is it possible that the parentId / parent of the parent you are trying to insert is in fact not null?  And you are getting that error because there isn't a category entity with that primaryKey.

Comment: @Carlos
Here is the saving category object
[Link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P8XzTzflgfffyVelxdRwGH68tIqjN1JV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Omid The screenshot show that `ParenId` is `0` (zero), which is not the same as `null` and most likely is causing the error.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks man
this silly issue ruined my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this where you handle input values:

```
if (category.ParentId == 0)
{
    category.ParentId = null;
}
```